# Typescript option. BaseUrl settings with nested directories

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When using 'baseUrl' property in combination with 'paths' property like so:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "app-component": [ "app/app.component"],
  "test-component": [ "app/test/test.component" ]
}
```

everything compiles fine but when changing to:

```
"baseUrl": "./src/app",
"paths": {
  "app-component": [ "app.component"],
  "test-component": [ "test/test.component" ]
}
```

compiler complains that it can not find referenced modules.

Is there something I'm missing from the docs or search logic implementation?

*Edit 1*

Modules are referenced as:

```
import { AppComponent } from 'app-component';
import { TestComponent } from 'test-component';
```

Comment: Any chance you could include how modules are referenced/imported?

Answer (score 0):

After checking pure tsc compilation (that did not yield any errors) and ejecting webpack.config.js with `ng eject` it turned out that modules property looked like:

```
"modules": [
  "./src",
  "./node_modules"
]
```

so provided error was not related to typescript but to webpack that simply could not find referenced files.